# How to build a facebook app with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I'm trying to load my ruby on rails root page welcome/index inside a Facebook canvas app.
My website : https://floating-fortress-9660.herokuapp.com/ and worked well

On facebook , I create app facebook , I set "App Face" and setting : canvas url :https://floating-fortress-9660.herokuapp.com/

Heroku page is working perfectly when direct url is used in browser, 
but generate a "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." when I'm trying to load it inside the canvas app.

I'm very grateful for all help. thank